# ListView crashing with fatal error when scrolling very quickly

Tags: listview, android-asynctask

I'm having an issue with a ListView that is causing my app to crash. The whole app doesn't crash, it just closes the view and reloads the main activity. It works fine seemingly, and when scrolling pretty fast it's mostly stable. But if I scroll up and down using fast scroll several times the screen will freeze and it will reload the main activity. Can someone help me find what the issue is? This is the error I receive from LogCat when it crashes:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 12439 (AsyncTask #4)
```

Here's a look at my code:

The getView() method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
            vi.setMinimumHeight(120);

            holder = new ViewHolder(); 
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon= (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        holder.position = kanji_ids.get(position);
        holder.context = vi.getContext();
        new DownloadAsyncTask().execute(holder);
        return vi;
    }
```

And here is the AsyncTask that fetches the data and displays it...

```
class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, ViewHolder> {
    String icon;
    String text;

    @Override
    protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];
        Context context = viewHolder.context;
        Database db = Database.getInstance(context);
        text = db.getPercentByPosition(viewHolder.position);
        icon = db.getIconByPosition(viewHolder.position);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder result) {
        if (result.icon == null) {
            result.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
        } else {
            result.icon.setImageResource(icon);
        }

        result.text.setText(text);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the icon is no longer visible and that view was reused for a new row when you scrolled. You should use [WeakReferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and check if the viewHolder or the icon are not null, if they are you can discard the changes. Same goes for the text.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm a bit confused on how to implement that. Do I make the holder's image view and text view weak references? Do I make the viewholder itself a weak reference?